# Navigate to a route programatically in ui-router-ng2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router-ng2 in an Angular 2 app. How do I tell the router, from JavaScript/Typescript, to navigate to a state? I'm looking for something like:

```
export class SomeClass {
    constructor(private router: UIRouter) { }
    somefunc() {
        if (some condition) {
            this.router.navigate("/whatever")
        } else {
            this.router.navigate("/home")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, using state names rather than urls.

```
import {UIRouter} from "ui-router-ng2";

export class SomeClass {

  constructor (private _uiRouter:UIRouter) {}

  somefunc() {
    if (some condition) {
      this._uiRouter.stateService.go('whatever')
    } else {
      this._uiRouter.stateService.go('home')
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: you may also inject `StateService` directly

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using dependency injection to get access to the `StateService`

try this in your angular `component`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { StateService } from "@uirouter/core";

@Component({selector: "app-component-name",})

export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private stateService: StateService) { }    
    ngOnInit() {}
    public someFunction(){
        this.stateService.go('your_named_state');
    }
}
```